# C3P0 - A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source

Tags: spring, jpa, c3p0

I have gone through many forum similar to this issues. But I still couldn't get the resolution.
Here is brief explanation about my application jar version and full stack trace details. if anybody has solution to this problem. Please help me.

```
Spring: <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
Hibernate: <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
JPA:spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C3P0:com.springsource.com.mchange.v2.c3p0-0.9.1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
application-context.xml

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>#{cpadbProps['cpa.jdbc.driverClassName']}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>#{cpadbProps['cpa.jdbc.url']}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>#{cpadbProps['cpa.jdbc.username']}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>#{cpadbProps['cpa.jdbc.password']}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSourceName" value="#{cpadbProps['cpa.applicationName']}" />     
        <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize']}</value></property> 
        <property name="minPoolSize"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize']}</value></property> 
        <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize']}</value></property> 
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts']}</value></property> 
        <property name="acquireIncrement"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement']}</value></property> 
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod']}</value></property> 
        <property name="maxIdleTime"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime']}</value></property> 
        <property name="maxConnectionAge"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge']}</value></property> 
        <property name="preferredTestQuery"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery']}</value></property>   
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin"><value>#{dbProps['hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin']}</value></property> 
        <property name="checkoutTimeout"><value>30000</value></property>
    </bean>

<!-- ************ JPA configuration ***********  -->    
    <bean id="cpaEntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
             <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
             <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
             </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.causeway.pm.cpaintegration.transferobjects"></property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="#{cpadbProps['cpa.hibernate.dialect']}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="#{dbProps['hibernate.show_sql']}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="#{dbProps['hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto']}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="#{dbProps['hibernate.jdbc.batch_size']}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="#{dbProps['hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size']}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="#{dbProps['hibernate.max_fetch_depth']}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultsets" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="30" />
                <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true" />

                <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path"
                    value="classpath:conf/ehcache.xml" />
                <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                    value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" /> 

            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="cpaEntityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="cpaTransactionManager" />
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dbProps.properties

hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=no-create

hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=20
hibernate.max_fetch_depth=2

hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize=10
hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize=1
hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize=25
hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=10
hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement=5
hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=10800
hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1;
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin=false
hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge=14400
hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime=21600

cpadbProps.properties

cpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
cpa.jdbc.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
cpa.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx-xxx:1433;databaseName=xxx

--------------------Error Stack Trace------------\\
<pre> <code>
2014-09-02 13:18:34,741 ERROR | http-bio-8080-exec-2 | com.causeway.pm.web.interceptor.RestExceptionProcessor  | Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection 
com.causeway.ctl.common.service.exception.ServiceException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at com.causeway.pm.cpaintegration.service.CpaServiceImpl.listContracts(CpaServiceImpl.java:62) ~[cpa-integration-1.0.jar:na]
    at com.causeway.pm.impl.service.ProjectServiceImpl.listCpaProjects(ProjectServiceImpl.java:53) ~[pm-impl-1.0.jar:na]
    at com.causeway.pm.web.controller.ProjectController.listCpaProjects(ProjectController.java:67) ~[ProjectController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at com.causeway.ctl.security.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:37) [ctl-security-1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:430) ~[spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.causeway.pm.cpaintegration.service.CpaServiceImpl.listContracts(CpaServiceImpl.java:57) ~[cpa-integration-1.0.jar:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67) ~[spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:110) ~[spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1351) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106) ~[com.springsource.com.mchange.v2.c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529) ~[com.springsource.com.mchange.v2.c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128) ~[com.springsource.com.mchange.v2.c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar:4.2.12.Final]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.

 - List item

    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319) ~[com.springsource.com.mchange.v2.c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557) ~[com.springsource.com.mchange.v2.c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477) ~[com.springsource.com.mchange.v2.c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525) ~[com.springsource.com.mchange.v2.c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is your configuration getting to the ComboPooledDataSource as you expect? c3p0 dumps configuration information on pool init (before it tries to acquire any Connections). Look in your logs at INFO for that config dump. Make sure that the jdbcUrl, user, and password properties of the ComboPooledDataSource are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Weird thing is that same configuration work fine if i start pointing to MySQL instance server instead of MS SQL Server where i am getting this error. is something related to database server installation.

Comment: can you get to the SQL Server instance at the jdbcUrl, user, and password you are supplying directly using the DriverManager class? that'd be a simple thing to try and debug. (if you want to, you can try `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource` rather than `ComboPooledDataSource` within the c3p0 libs. but the simplest thing to do, less to worry about and debug, would just be to write a test program and call `DriverManager.getConnection( ... )` yourself.

Comment: Your issue resolved?? I am also facing the similar issue. It will be great help of you provide me the solution